# matrix space in txt file in disk vs size in memory

Tags: r

I have a matrix in a txt file on disk(35 GBs), when i try to create a matrix of this size in R, there is an error (cannot allocate vector of size 130 GB), how come the size on disk is 35GB and the space in memory 130GBs.